# Plane mesh doesn't show up in Collection?

Tags: mesh, collections

I'm a beginner when it comes to blender but I've learned a lot in the past few days. I started a new project where I was messing with the shape of a cube. The cube was showing up in the collection on the upper right. However, when I added a plane mesh (also through Shift-A) it doesn't show up in the collection. Is this a glitch or am I missing something?

Comment: You probably added the new mesh while still in edit mode. Adding a mesh in edit mode simply makes it a part of the mesh you are already editing (just counts it as extra faces of the same mesh) and therefore will not appear in the outliner. Make sure you switch to object mode before adding a new mesh if you want it to be a separate object.

Comment: It sounds as if you may have added the plane when you were in Edit mode. If you did, the plane will actually be part of the cube rather than a separate mesh. If you want to add a new object, you must make sure you're in Object mode before using Shift-A! To check, Press 'A' in Edit mode which will select the whole object and probably include both the cube and plane.